# Scala - How to get all the fields name from an Avro schema?

Tags: java, scala, avro

I have an example Avro schema:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "wpmcn.MyPair",
    "doc": "A pair of strings",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "left", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "right", "type": "string"}
    ]
}
```

In Java, this would be a way to get all the field names:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Schema schema =
         new Schema.Parser().parse(AvroTest.class.getClassLoader().
           getResourceAsStream("pair.avsc"));

     //Collect all field values to an array list
     List<String> fieldValues = new ArrayList<>();
     for(Field field : schema.getFields()) {
         fieldValues.add(field.name());
     }

     //Iterate the arraylist
     for(String value: fieldValues)  {
         System.out.println(value);
     }
}
```

How do I do the same using Scala?

Comment: This does not look like a StackOverFlow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
avroSchema.getFields.asScala.map(_.name())) //forEach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val myAvroSchemaText= io.Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("pair.avsc")).mkString
val avroSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(myAvroSchemaText)

avroSchema.getFields().foreach {
  f =>
    println(f.name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. How would you check if in the whole `avroSchema` exists element `null`? Is there a `contain` or something similar so that we do not need to iterate 1 by 1 element and check?

Comment: @user9750148   schema contains all the elements specified in the file. It has no data, just the schema. not sure what you are trying to ascertain, but if you have a schema in your hand as a reference, then there should be no need to do any check, you can simply use *that* schema. otherwise, the avsc file has everything mentioned in it. hth